# Are pipe() and socket() thread safe? (double close() problem)

Tags: linux, c++11, thread-safety, file-descriptor

I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0`

`uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.18.0-17-generic #18~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 15 15:27:12 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I thought all system calls that create file descriptors are thread safe on `Linux`.
I mean, calling `socket()` and `pipe()` in parallel from different threads shouldn't return the **same** fd. 
Isn't it true?

Comment: What do the man pages say?

Comment: There's nothing about the `thread` word in both of them that I found.

Comment: Though it looks like you have all sorts of race conditions in that...

Comment: It happens also when calling `socket()` concurrently from 2 different threads

Comment: Hmm, well I'll try to change my application: when `close()` is issued, it doesn't mean `s`, `p[0]` or `p[1]` value is changed. So this program isn't quite correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that fair because I didn't really show any real code, but I want to answer my own question to the sake of other users.

- The symptoms I saw were errors like

  - `errno 9 (Bad file descriptor)`
  - Application dead lock (due to communication to other processes on bad file descriptors)
- This is a multithreaded environment.
- I started to had a doubts about `socket()` and `pipe()` to be not multithread safe due to logs I added in order to debug. I saw the same fd used by two different threads at the same time (I didn't put logs in all the relevant places, that's why I saw this strange occurance).
- Thanks to this [Double close()](https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/multi-thread-specific-bugs) paragraph, I understood it was a variation of my problem:

  - Thread 1 `open()` fd `100`
  - Thread 1 `close()` fd `100`. **Close #1 <--- this was the bug**
  - Thread 2 `open()` fd `100` (totally fine now where `100` isn't used by any thread in the process)
  - Thread 1 `close()` **again** fd `100`. **Close #2.**

    - This second `close()` actually closes fd `100` of Thread 2. Then when Thread 2 use this fd, it would get `errno 9 (Bad file descriptor)` for using a closed fd.
    - It may also get more complicated: in this moment fd `100` is closed. It may be re-opened by another thread which uses it with `read()/write()`. Thread 2 would use it as well with `read()/write()` - this scenario where two threads use the same fd is wrong and invalidates the data sent/received on that fd.

Comment: This is why you should not use a closed FD on purpose, with the expectation it's safe because you will get an error.

Comment: Why would I want to use a closed FD on purpose ?

Comment: Programmers often believe that closing a FD in a thread is a reliable way to cancel a socket operation in another (that has started, is about to start, may have finished...).

Answer (score 1):

In your example program, you have [data races](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races) on every single one of your global variables except `pI` and `sI`. You read them from one thread while writing to them from another. This leads to undefined behavior, meaning any result you get from that program is meaningless.

Both the [`socket`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Socket.html) and the [`pipe`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html) functions are thread-safe, as well as safe to use from asynchronous signal handlers. Oddly enough, the man pages don't include that bit of information, but the online documentation does.

Comment: Which outline documentation? Can you please share a link?

Comment: The documentation for both funtions is linked in my answer.